# Difference-frequency-generated (DFG) spectral width

Tags: optics, laser, wavelength, non-linear-optics

If we have two laser beams with central wavelengths $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, (one with a spectral width of $\Delta\lambda_2$ and one with negligible spectral width), interacting in a non-linear crystal, how would we calculate the spectral width of the difference-frequency-generated (DFG) output?
I know it's a Lorentzian given by $\Delta\lambda = \frac{4\lambda_1^2\Delta\lambda_2}{4(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2-\Delta\lambda_2^2}$. But I don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

Difference frequency generation (DFG) is a stimulated parametric down-conversion process, which implies conservation of energy. It manifests in the relationship among the frequencies of the three beams (the pump, the seed and the idler or DFG beam):
$$ \omega_p-\omega_s = \omega_i . $$
In terms of wavelengths it becomes
$$ \lambda_i = \frac{\lambda_2\lambda_1}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1} , $$
where $\lambda_1$ is the pump wavelength and $\lambda_2$ is the seed wavelength.
Assuming the pump has a negligible bandwidth, the bandwidth of the idler is determined by the bandwidth of the seed. To determine the idler bandwidth, we use
$$ \Delta\lambda_i 
= \left|\frac{\partial\lambda_i(\lambda_2)}{\partial\lambda_2}\right|\Delta\lambda_2
=\left|\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}
-\frac{\lambda_2\lambda_1}{(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2}\right|\Delta\lambda_2
= \frac{\lambda_1^2\Delta\lambda_2}{(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2} . $$
The resulting expression follows from that provided by the OP by setting $\Delta\lambda_2^2=0$ since it would be small compared to the other term in the denominator. If this is not the case, the bandwidth would also depend on the shape of the spectrum.

Comment: Thank you for your response @flippiefanus. I could derive the same result you've given, but couldn't understand how to end up with a Lorentzian. As in to formally prove the result given in the question.

Comment: Where did you find the Lorentzian result?